# ProgressBar not starting, not going in foreach loop until window not closed

Tags: c#, wpf

I work on an export plugin to export revit models to database.

To do this, my main window is calling ExportEngine which is a Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using UserConnect;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;

namespace UserConnect
{
    public partial class ExportEngine : Window
    {

        private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
        private static String zoneName = "REVIT";
        private User user;
        private Server neo4j = new Server("172.16.1.104", 8000);

        public ExportEngine(User userp)
        {
            user = userp;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void addComponent(Component c)
        {
            components.Add(c);
        }

        public bool save()
        {
            this.ShowDialog();
            float progress = components.Count / 100;
            
            foreach (Component c in components)
            {
               //Here is my export request, working good
               pbStatus.Value+=progress;
            }

            this.Close();
            return result;
        } 
    }
}
```

I call this in Main :

```
db = new ExportEngine(user);
foreach(String name in mats)
{
    Component c = new Component(name, "m2",1);
    db.addComponent(c);
}
db.save();
```

I don't understand why my save() starts only after I close the progressbar Window, and this progressbar doesn't move at all (no progress).

Comment: What progress bar? I can't see reference to one in the code you have posted.

Comment: I just edited it to show pbStatus wich is my progressBar in xaml file

Answer (score 0):

### `save` doesnt run until windows is closed

`ShowDialog` does not return until the window you are showing is closed. That explains why it does not run until the windows closes.

### Progress bar doesn't update

Try this.

```
pbStatus.MaxValue = components.Count; //make sure you set the max value

foreach (Component c in components)
{
    pbStatus.Value+= 1; //increment by one item as you have processed on item.
}
```

Comment: So how can i do? I mean how to show the window while the loop is in progress? I edited my code to add the progression part, i deleted my query from the code but i deleted the progression update too ^^"